# How can i create image gallery in UIWebView using Objective-C ?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have an html encoded string

`desc = "&lt;p&gt;Dear Participant,&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;We are great full to announce that we are having a treasure hunt near Babagosh.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;You are&lt;/b&gt;&amp;nbsp;requested to attend the said event at&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Date: 27-09-2016&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Time: 10:00 am to 16:00 am&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://api.theweek.com/sites/default/files/legacygeneric/Islamabad_fall_690.jpg&quot; style=&quot;width: 690px;&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;We will be looking forward for you.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Regards:&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt;TPLMaps Treasure Hunt Team&lt;/p&gt;";`

What i need to do is merge array of images with html string in a way that it can be display like slideshow.

Please Guide.